# Laravel Many to Many How to form query in eloquent or in query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.5

From the following query im getting the expected result:

```
SELECT *
    FROM rooms r
    JOIN amenities_room am 
      ON r.id = am.room_id 
    JOIN amenities a 
      ON am.amenities_id = a.id
     AND a.id IN (2,3)
GROUP BY r.id
  HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

How can i for the query in laravel way in (Eloquent or in Query Builder)

Note:
The following tables are involved:

**rooms**
id
number
name

**amenities**
id
name

**amenities_room**
room_id
amenities_id

Comment: `rooms` has many `amenities? `amenities` belongs to `amenities_room`?! You should edit your question and tell us the relationships between the models. If it's 1:N or N:N. I suggest you read the docummentation first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: please accept any of the answer which solved your problem to close this question and upvote any/all answer that has helped to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$rooms = Room::with('amenities')
->withCount('amenities', function($query){
  $query->whereIn('id', [2, 3]);
})
->where('amenities_count', 2)
->get()
```

Docs for counting related models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Sorry for the edits, had to do some more research than I thought to get this.

Comment: message": "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You got this error `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` because your eloquent is expecting a string but you have passed an object here in `withCount()` try this

```
$rooms = Room::with('amenities')
->withCount('amenities')->where(function($query){
  $query->whereIn('id', [2, 3]);
})
->where('amenities_count', 2)
->get()
```